# How is TAS affected by wind?

Tags: airspeed, jet, groundspeed

Does True Air Speed (TAS) change with wind speed and direction?

My understanding is that if an aircraft were travelling at 470kt TAS, with a hundred knot tailwind, the ground speed would be 570kt. In this case the TAS would remain the same, regardless of the wind, but the ground speed would change.

Comment: True airspeed is relative to the air mass you are flying through, so yes, TAS is not affected by wind speed.

Comment: Note that sudden changes of the wind speed do affect the TAS. Due to the inertia of the aircraft instantaneous changes in groundspeed are impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct.  True airspeed refers to the actual speed which the aircraft is moving through the air.  Ground speed is the speed at which the aircraft moves over the ground.  The formula

$v_\text{ground} = v_\text{true} - v_\text{wind} \cdot \cos(\alpha)$

Where

- $v_\text{true}$ is the true airspeed
- $v_\text{ground}$ is the groundspeed
- $v_\text{wind}$ is the magnitude of the winds aloft
- $\alpha$ is the angle of the winds aloft relative to the longitudinal axis of the aircraft.